# Deleted question (on Meta)

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deletion

I'm curious why [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21488) was deleted? Sure, it's a little weird, but I'm guessing there's an easy answer to it. (And the OP has asked it again, on main. Again.)

Comment: That question seems more like a trolling attempt than anything sincere.

Comment: @AsafKaragila How strange it may seem, I think the question is genuine.

Comment: If it is genuine, why did the OP not use the original registered account to post this request?

Comment: @Asaf Isn't it obvious? To use that account would be too traumatic an experience given the number issue. Seriously, how inconsiderate of you! :-)

Comment: @quid: I guess I just don't care about human emotions more than I care about numbers?

Comment: >10k users have all the fun. :(

Comment: (Someone downvoted this question after I made my comment.  Just for the record, it wasn't me.)

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche : You'll see the dark side of stackexchange once you reach $10k$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OP doesn't have [sufficient privilege to participate on meta](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta). It is unfair to other users to allow this user to "skip the line". (Especially as it is clear that that user has little intention on properly using the site. They claim to have a "real" account, which *should* have sufficient privilege to participate here, and they are welcome to post their question on meta with *that* account.)

Comment: Apparently he has another "unlucky" identity, probably with more than 5 rep, so I don't see the harm of answering it. (This way, it will probably just resurface on main until he's suspended.)

Comment: @mrf If that account gets blocked for not following the basic guidelines of the site, I wouldn't call it a loss. I'd only wish I could do the same to their alleged "real" account. Heck, if they don't like their UID, just start another account.. like they did.

Comment: I agree, the question is weird at best. And I'd be really annoyed if someone wanted to swap UID with me as well. On the other hand, I agree with most rep caps, and I wasn't aware that it took 5 rep to participate on Meta, but ut would seem reasonable to allow questions from anyone here ... after all, it's better to ask about site policies before making a fool of yourself on main, isn't it?

Comment: Arthur, and then they can even merge the old account into a new one, thus having a new user ID number.

Comment: There are no rep limits for particpation on [über-meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=newest&pageSize=50), and that question would similarly fall under the purview of _that_ site. But users are expected to have some minimal familiarity with the main site before particpating on child-metas.

Comment: So, I guess I should have upvoted the question before voting to migrate it (which would have put him at 6 rep)? Not that I thought the question deserved an upvote.

Comment: @mrf I think it's generally bad to upvote _blatantly_ off-topic questions. You can always bestow your upvotes if/when the question gets migrated to a proper place.

Comment: I do as well, which is why I didn't. I have a feeling that the OP had no idea where and why his first question disappeared though.

Comment: @mrf: I have a feeling that the OP knew *exactly* what's going on...

Answer (score 6):

> I have a registered account that I don't like its number because it **reminds** me a **special date** that I lost a good friend.

Literally one sentence later:

> Unfortunately I **noticed** this fact **too late** when the number of my posts reached to a point that I can't ignore it to simply delete my account and open a new one with a different number.

Obvious troll is obvious.

---

To those who, thus far, disagree with my claim, I would like to indicate some further evidence. Anyone genuinely interested in trading accounts would be unlikely to add the reply of "User 1":

> I will not make any deals with you. I've registered to this forum. My account will **not be removed, relocated, exchanged or renumbered**! My account is my own. Please leave me alone and don't ping me again.

which in itself already has a scent of artificiality over it (emphasis mine). Especially considering the reply of "User 2":

> Your offer is really strange but I care about the **humans' emotion** much more than the numbers. If having an account with such a number is that important for you and makes you really happy, I have no problem with the exchange **if the system administrators** have no problem with it. You should **ask them about it**.

Everything is pointing too perfectly towards the meta question subsequently asked. Furthermore the writing style of the post and the two "User" replies is strikingly similar.

As a final point I'd like to indicate that the "offer" that was allegedly made is rather complex and therefore unlikely to yield answers so precisely aimed at what OP intended to ask.

Comment: I'd add "Accidentally I found two (not too active) accounts with my favorite numbers that are related to two very sweet events in my life." to the list.

Comment: Actually, my question wasn't at all about the quality (which is clearly bad, or at the very least extremely odd) of the deleted question or whether is was a trolling post or not (I'm not entirely convinced either way), but just why it was deleted. As made clear by Arthur, it was deleted because it was migrated from main and originated from a user without meta participation privilege, **not** because it was lacking in quality. As such, I don't think your answer addresses my question at all.

Comment: @mrf Well, excuse me for misunderstanding "why was it deleted" as a question about possible reasons for deletion. Obvious trolling fits that description pretty neatly in my book.